# how do I use link_to link to different controller and model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have the following for-loop.  This is in the '`view/vendor/show.html`'.

I set up a '`vendor :has_many :reviews`' and this is the for-loop:

```
<% for review in @vendor.reviews %>

    <%= review.user_id %>
    <%= review.summary %><br />

    <%= link_to 'More', @review%>

    <hr class="left span-5" />

<% end %>
```

For the `link_to` I would like it to link to the URL: reviews/:review_id

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "More", review_path(@review) %>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks -- I get an error:

review_url failed to generate from {:action=>"show", :controller=>"reviews", :id=>nil}, expected: {:controller=>"reviews", :action=>"show"}, diff: {:id=>nil}

Comment: I think I got it to work, thanks....in what situations would @review work and not work?  I needed to use review.id instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your code right now wouldn't work,

```
link_to 'More', @review
```

you want just review (without the @)  @review is not defined anywhere in your code.

Assuming you have your routes set up properly,

```
link_to 'More', review
```

should suffice.  Of course Brian's code does the same thing (again, without the @ though).  Rails can automatically figure out the proper path if you just use the object directly (using polymorphic routes) or with brian's:

```
link_to 'More', review_path(review)
```

Is the same as review_path(review.id)  Rails automatically takes the id of the object being referenced

Comment: Yeah, this is right, I stole the @review from her code, and I didn't even notice that it was review, and not @review. Good catch.